# How do I assert the unexistance of a model in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, cucumber

How do I assert that a user was not created while using Cucumber? In RSpec, I would use the following block, which I can not translate to Cucumber:

```
...
describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a new user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
end

# Cucumber equivalent
When /^he submits invalid information$/ do
  click_button "Sign up"
end
Then /^an account should not be created$/ do
  # not sure how to translate the expect block
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, you'll know the email that the user would use, so you could:

```
Then /^an account should not be created$/ do
  User.where(email: "youremail@example.com").first.should be_nil
end
```

Comment: Just curious, what if we want to be more granular and test a scenario where the user enters no input at all. In that case we will not be able to use the `User.where(email: ...)` since no email address was provided.

Comment: ismaelga's answer is a fine way to do that test. You could also store off @user_count and test it later.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
Given I have 3 users
When I submit with invalid information
Then I should have 3 users
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda to directly translate your RSpec test, rather than rely on a workaround.

```
Then /^an account should not be created$/ do
  save = lambda { click_button :submit }
  expect(save).not_to change(User, :count)
end
```